# Python handle 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' error with if else statement

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am using beautifulsoup4 to grab stock data and send to a spreadsheet in python. The problem I am having is that I cannot get my loop to skip over attributes that return None. So what I am needing is the code to add null values to rows where 
attribute would return none.

```
//my dictionay for storing data
data = {
    'Fiscal Quarter End' : [],
    'Date Reported' : [],
    'Earnings Per Share' : [],
    'Consensus EPS* Forecast' : [],
    '% Surprise' : []
}

    url = ""
    html = requests.get(url)
    data = html.text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)


    table = soup.find("div", class_="genTable")
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:

        if row.has_attr('tr'):

            cols = row.find_all("td")
            data['Fiscal Quarter End'].append( cols[0].get_text() )
            data['Date Reported'].append( cols[1].get_text() )
            data['Earnings Per Share'].append( cols[2].get_text() )
            data['Consensus EPS* Forecast'].append( cols[3].get_text() )
            data['% Surprise'].append( cols[4].get_text() )
        else:
            //where i need to add in the empty 'n/a' values
            data['Fiscal Quarter End'].append() 
            data['Date Reported'].append()
            data['Earnings Per Share'].append() 
            data['Consensus EPS* Forecast'].append()
            data['% Surprise'].append()
```

Comment: `//` is not a comment in Python...

Comment: you are defining a dictionary named data, then assiging html.text to data, then expecting data to be the dictionary.

Comment: You are using the data variable first as a dictionary then you also use it as a string which stores the HTML text. This will definitely cause you problems. Could you also clarify why you need to add in "empty" data?

Comment: if find_all returns empty, I want the rows empty. I need those empty rows into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `data` variable for two different things. The second usage overwrote your dictionary. It is simpler to just use `html.text` in the call to `soup.find()`. Try the following:

```
import requests
import bs4    

# My dictionary for storing data
data = {
    'Fiscal Quarter End' : [],
    'Date Reported' : [],
    'Earnings Per Share' : [],
    'Consensus EPS* Forecast' : [],
    '% Surprise' : []
    }

empty = 'n/a'
url = ""
html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("div", class_="genTable")
rows = []

if table:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all("td")
        data['Fiscal Quarter End'].append(cols[0].get_text())
        data['Date Reported'].append(cols[1].get_text())
        data['Earnings Per Share'].append(cols[2].get_text())
        data['Consensus EPS* Forecast'].append(cols[3].get_text())
        data['% Surprise'].append(cols[4].get_text())

if len(rows) == 0:
    # Add in the empty 'n/a' values if no columns found
    data['Fiscal Quarter End'].append(empty) 
    data['Date Reported'].append(empty)
    data['Earnings Per Share'].append(empty) 
    data['Consensus EPS* Forecast'].append(empty)
    data['% Surprise'].append(empty)
```

In the event the `table` or `rows` was empty, `data` would hold the following:

```
{'Date Reported': ['n/a'], 'Earnings Per Share': ['n/a'], '% Surprise': ['n/a'], 'Consensus EPS* Forecast': ['n/a'], 'Fiscal Quarter End': ['n/a']}
```